# Pthread_mutex_lock crashes when locking from 2 different threads

Tags: c++, pthreads, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I'm using Pthread and Pthread_mutex for a project. I have timers that periodically create a thread using SIGEV_THREAD(). In my code, I have a timer that triggers a thread every 5 seconds and another that triggers every 15 seconds.

one of the thread executes this code
[Radar.cpp]

```
void Radar::executeRadar(){
    std::cout << "***Executing radar***" << std::endl;

    pthread_mutex_lock( &this->airplaneDB->mutex);

    this->scanAirZone(this->airplaneDB->getPlanes());

    pthread_mutex_unlock( &this->airplaneDB->mutex);
}
```

and the other executes this
[Display.cpp]

```
 pthread_mutex_lock( &this->planeDB->mutex);

// Some stuff

  pthread_mutex_unlock( &this->planeDB->mutex);
```

The pointers "this" in this case are two different objects. The pointers planeDB and airplaneDB point to the same object.

I want to create a mutex that allows only one function to read the content of the airplaneDB at ay given time. However, when running the code, I get an error when the 2 threads try to run at the same time. Basically, they both try to lock and I get this:

```
Process 655382 (FlightSimulator) terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 ip=000000010002d41d(/usr/lib/ldqnx-64.so.2@pthread_mutex_lock+0x000000000000000d) mapaddr=000000000002d41d. ref=0000000000000000
```

In AirplaneDB, the mutex is initialized the following way:

```
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);

    pthread_mutex_init(&this->mutex, &attr);
```

Any Ideas?

## Update:

The problem was caused by an improper setting of a pointer in one of the classes. Therefore trying to lock a mutex at address 0. This line should have pointed me towards the answer:

```
@pthread_mutex_lock+0x000000000000000d
```

Initializing the DB properly fixed the error.

Comment: Silly question, but since there is no mcve, i don't have much choice. You ask your mutex to be cross-process-shared. Any particular reason for that ? If so, Your mutex object should reside in a shared memory block. For that to be the case with this code, `planeDB` and `airplaneDB` would have to refer to said-same shared memory block. So, was process-sharing the mutex just a grasp? Honestly, I'd be more inclined to think one of those four pointer (two this, planeDB, and airplaneDB) are potentially invalid.

Comment: It was only a relic of me trying to find a solution. I found a very old blog where the OP had a similar problem (which included shared memory). One of the solutions included this line of code PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED.

Comment: I also thought this was unnecessary as my program only operates on threads... But I'm at a loss right now and can't figure out a solution so can't hurt to try anything.

Comment: If the fault is in mutex-lock (and it appears it is), then the only logical conclusion is the mutex structure, passed by address, isn't valid, which means the *probability* is that `planeDB` and/or `airplaneDB` (whichever code path that got you there) isn't valid. If all you have to debug this is stdout/err instrumentation I'd dump those addresses before each entrance. It may be illuminating. If they stay consistent, then look for a potential overwrite in the same object (i.e. what comes *before* the mute in that structure) and a potential breech by some action there.

Comment: Your idea turned out to be a good one. Displaying the addresses showed that one of the db's was passed improperly. Thus creating a pointer at address 0. Thank you, your patience did help me find the problem! Have a good day!